# Firebase Cloud Functions Scheduler Location

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have located my App Engine in Europe-West1. To make Cloud Functions Scheduler work it seems that it needs to be located in the same region.
For whatever reason it won't let me deploy that function to that region. Any idea what is missing here.

```
exports.zipImages = functions.region('europe-west1').pubsub.schedule('0 12 * * *').onRun((context) => {
    return console.log("Zipper Schedule running!");
})
```

> i  functions: creating Node.js 8 function zipImages(europe-west1)...
>
> ✔  scheduler: all necessary APIs are enabled
>
> ✔  pubsub: all necessary APIs are enabled
>
> Error: HTTP Error: 400, Location must equal europe-west1 because the App Engine app that is associated with this project is located in europe-west1

Comment: As i can understand you are already deployed a Cloud Function i another region, you can check this in your console going to Function tab. If this function is in another region you must deploy a new function in europe-west1.

Comment: All my functions are located in europe-west1 now. It still won't let me deploy the new function.

Comment: If deployment isn't working the way you expect, contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: For whatever reason I was able to deploy it today. I changed nothing but only tried again. Maybe a glitch! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was only a glitch as it worked without any problems another day.